# Typescript: union in function parameter causes error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Coming from Flow this used to be fine but apparently not the case in TS and I can't find a decent example online:

```
type Props = {
    fnA(string, string | object): void; 
                    // ^ Unexpected token, expected "," 
    fnB(string, any): void; // No problems with this 
}
```

What is the correct way to write a union type for a function parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the peculiarity of TypeScript syntax: in a function type, you must give names to all parameters:

```
type Props = {
    fnA(a: string, b: string | object): void; 

    fnB(string, any): void; // string, any are parameter names, not types
}
```

In the second function `fnB`, `string` and `any` are confusingly interpreted not as types, but as argument names that have implicit `any` type - if you had `--noImplicitAny` option turned on, you'd get an error about that.